# Grails / GORM : org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xyz (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

**Edit:** got a -1, could you please explain why? I searched for duplicates and did not find any.

Posting a Q/A for the issue I just encountered:

```java
class Pineapple {
    def pineappleService

    Supplier supplier;

    def beforeInsert() {
        pineappleService.beforeInsert(this);
    }
}

class PineappleService {
    def beforeInsert(Pineapple pineapple) {
         Pineapple.withNewSession {
             // some logic
             pineapple.supplier.save();
         }
    }
}
```

Exception:

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xyz (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to move the closure to the domain class:

```java
class Pineapple {
    def pineappleService

    Supplier supplier;

    def beforeInsert() {
        Pineapple.withNewSession {
            pineappleService.beforeInsert(this);
        }
    }
}

class PineappleService {
    def beforeInsert(Pineapple pineapple) {
         // some logic
         pineapple.supplier.save();
    }
}
```

Documentation:

- [GORM: Events and Auto Timestamping](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

> Notice the usage of withNewSession method above. Since events are
>   triggered whilst Hibernate is flushing using persistence methods like
>   save() and delete() won't result in objects being saved unless you run
>   your operations with a new Session.
>
> Fortunately the withNewSession method lets you share the same
>   transactional JDBC connection even though you're using a different
>   underlying Session.

- https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html